# Containing a draggable div inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working with the jqueryUI draggable plugin. I have been able to set it up easily. Now I have a basic table that I placed the draggable div inside. How would I be able  to keep the draggable div to be contained inside the `<td id=” middle-side”></td>`? In other words keep the div inside and making only draggable inside `<td id=” middle-side”></td>` [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/)

HTML

```
<table style="width: 95%; height: 600px;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <h1 class="someTitle"></h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left-side"></td>
            <td class="middle-side">
                Keep me inside here!
                    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
                        <p><b>Drag me around</b></p>
                    </div>

            </td>
            <td style="border: 2px solid;">
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td class="bottom-side" colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Jquery

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the documentation: [containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment)

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

Answer (score 0):

just add { containment: "parent" } inside your draggable function

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
});
```